# click listener for button inside list view in android

Tags: android, listview, clicklistener

In my android app I have a list and in each row I have a `button`. On pressing the `button`, another `activity` should open. I am a little confused how to do the click listener. Can anyone kindly suggest ? Thanks.

note: i can create a click listened inside the array adapter. However, I am unable to start a new activity from there :(

Answer (score 4):

Put a button in your custom view and handle click event in getView method.

Your code should look something like this.

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
{
   if(convertView == null)
   {
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView  = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT, null);
   }

   Button yourButton= (Button)  convertView  .findViewById(R.id.YOUR_BUTTON_ID);

   yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
   { 
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) 
       {
           // Your code that you want to execute on this button click
           Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
           CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

       }

   });    
   return convertView ;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

where ever you are inflating the row view, get the reference to the button in the listItem, and add clickListener to it. You set the listener by

```
button.setOnClickListener()
```

and in the listener click call new `activity`.

declare a field your activity class like this-

```
private Context mCurrentContext = this;
```

and when you call the new Activity,

```
mCurrentContext.startActivity(Intent, int);
```

Comment: I have tried this, the problem is this: `startactivity` is not recognized as a function. error msg: `the method startActivity(Intent, int) is undefined for the type new View.onClickListener(){}`

Comment: then just try by making a method that does the activity starting bit, and let this method be called in the onClick segment..

Comment: @Urban : that did it..however, i dont see anything in the webview, but the title s loading fine...previously it used to work just fine..not sure whats the problem here :( ..will ask in a separate question