# How can I find my button ID's in a ListView row Android Java?

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, button

I have 1 listview, 5 rows, so when I run the code, I got 5 item_Titel, 5 item_Datum, 5 item_Intro and 5 item_Button. But I don't know how I can find the R.Id. from each item, each row. When u use loose textviews and buttons you can call it in your XML like: @id/"clicked_button1", @id/"clicked_button2', @id/"clicked_button3" etc.

Then I can use switch case and fill it, 
example:

```
public class OnClick implements OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
                   case R.id.clicked_Button1:
                 Url = 1;
                      break;

               case R.id.clicked_Button2:           
                         Url = 2;
                          break;

               case R.id.clicked_Button2:           
                         Url = 3;
                          break;
```

But now I'm using a listview.. But how can I find out which R.id."item_Button???!!!" 
I need to use now?

I hope my question / explanation is a bit clearer now! ;-)

Thank you for helping me!

Added XML item_view:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_Titel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_Datum"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_Titel"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="13dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/item_Intro"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_Datum"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/item_Button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/item_Intro"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
                android:padding="9dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="10dp" />

     </RelativeLayout>
```

Added XML activity_main:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

        android:background="@drawable/tmx_background_portrait" 

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        tools:context=".MainActivity" >

      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/TVLoading"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
          android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
          android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
          android:textSize="20dp"
          android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/PostListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Here a part of my MainActivity where I try to read and control my buttons:

```
    public class OnClick implements OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            switch (v.getId()) {

            case R.id.item_Button???!!!:
                Url = 1;
                break;

    /*      
            case R.id.item_Button???!!!:
                Url = 2;
                break;

            case R.id.item_Button???!!!:
                Url = 3;
                break;
           */

               }
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    }
```

Here the ListAdapter part and getView part:

```
    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Post> {
    public MyListAdapter() {
        super(MainActivity.this, R.layout.item_view, myPost);   
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View itemView = convertView;
        if (itemView == null) {
            itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, 
                             parent, false);
        }

        Post currentPost = myPost.get(position);

        // Titel:
        TextView TitelText = (TextView) 
                     itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_Titel);
        TitelText.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentPost.getTitel()));

        // Datum:
        TextView DatumText = (TextView) 
                     itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_Datum);
        DatumText.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentPost.getDatum()));

        // Intro:
        TextView IntroText = (TextView) 
                     itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_Intro);
        IntroText.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentPost.getIntro()));

        // Button:
        Button ButtonNumber = (Button) 
                     itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_Button);
        ButtonNumber.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentPost.getButton()));
        ButtonNumber.setOnClickListener(new OnClick());

        return itemView;

    }               
}
```

Comment: Why are the IDs random? Are they not defined in your XML Layout? If they are created in your java, then keep a reference to them when you create them. If your question is about finding which button called OnClick (You have assigned the same OnClickListener to many buttons), then you can use the "View" which is passed in as a param and cast it back to a button. I'm not really sure what this question is asking, but this might help.

Comment: Do you have 5 Listview items each containing a Button or every single ListView item contains 5 Buttons ?

Comment: It will be easy to understand if you post your XML and some code.

Comment: You need to have a custom adapter class where you can set `onClickListener` in your Button. Have a look at [this](http://looksok.wordpress.com/tag/listview-item-with-button/) example

Comment: You should create an item class and a custom view inflator. Take a look here: [link](http://hmkcode.com/android-custom-listview-items-row/)

Comment: I changed / updated my question, explanation and code clearer. I hope it is better now! Already, Thanks..

Comment: I'm still a little lost here on what you're going for here, but I'm going to take a shot. You know the URL when you're creating the view right? Can't you just create a constructor in your OnClick class accepts the URL, then have the that act on the link?

Comment: Have you figured this out? If any of the answers below helped you, you should accept it as an answer you used. Otherwise, post your own solution and accept that.

Comment: It still doesn't work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        // Button:
        Button ButtonNumber = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_Button);
        ButtonNumber.setTag(currentPost.getButtonid()); 
        ButtonNumber.setText(Html.fromHtml(currentPost.getButton()));
        ButtonNumber.setOnClickListener(new OnClick());

        Log.e("ButtonNumber.setId", "Found:" + ButtonNumber.getTag());
```

I add the line with the .setTag() in it. Now it is working great!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you have a listview that is populate with 5 rows. In each of row, you have text and buttons.

When you inflate your row in the array adapter, you need to get the button and attach the listener.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
        row = inflater.inflate(mLayoutResourceId, parent, false);
    }
    Button button = (Button)row.findViewById(R.id.item_Button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}
```

Here is a link that is similar to your issue.
[click listener for button inside list view in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502866/click-listener-for-button-inside-list-view-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "int position" variable in the getView() function to infer which item on the list it is. Then, assign the the URL based on that, and not based on your button ID (you can be sure the "position" variable will correspond the order of the view in your Adapter). Do not use your OnClick class at all. After you figure out what URL you want to use in your getView() function, you can use setTag() and getTag() functions to "store" any Object (in this case, it's a String) in your actual Button instance (or any instance of an object that extends View).

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View itemView = convertView;
    if (itemView == null) {
        itemView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_view, 
                         parent, false);
    }

    ...

    String url;
    switch(position){
        case 0: url = "url for the 1 button"; break;
        case 1: url = "url for the 2 button"; break;
        case 2: url = "url for the 3 button"; break;
        case 3: url = "url for the 4 button"; break;
        case 4: url = "url for the 5 button"; break;
        default: url = "http://www.google.com"; break;
    }
    Button button = (Button)itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_Button);
    button.setTag(url);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = (String)v.getTag();
            //do what you need with URL
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });
    return itemView;
}
```